# PowerPoint VBA to get selected cell and row and column

Tags: powerpoint, selection

I am trying to use VBA and C# to determine the selected range of cells in a PowerPoint table. Ideally, I could use something like the .Start and .End properties of the selected range of cells to identify the row and column boundaries of the selected range of cells, but I could find no such properties.

But I cannot find any way to get the cell coordinates from the selection object. I want to use something like this:

```
var startColumn = selection.ShapeRange.Table.<selected cellrange>.Start;
```

The only thing I found that was even close was some code that looped over each cell in the selected table object asking if each cell was selected.

```
For x = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
    For y = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
        If oTbl.Cell(x, y).Selected Then
        ' do something with the selected cell or indexes
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Is that the only way for me to determine the row and column of the selected cell, or is there a shorter way? Thank you.

Comment: What you have is the best PPT has to offer. If I had to do this often, I'd probably turn this into a function that returns the cell coordinates or a reference to the cell.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. That is exactly what I did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Steve Rindsberg confirmed that PowerPoint has no functions for this sort of thing. I used the code shown above to traverse the table cells to find the selected region.